# Why writing through a pointer to a moved variable has not been decided as UB in Rust?

Tags: rust, undefined-behavior

I am investigating possible reasons that prevent the Rust compiler from optimizing [certain code pieces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67499399/why-does-the-rust-compiler-not-reuse-the-memory-on-the-stack-after-an-object-is). I found [this comment](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/59123#issuecomment-501089032) in an issue in rust-lang that alerts me.

> We must not optimize away storage of locals that are mutably borrowed, because as @matthewjasper notes in #61430, it isn't decided that the following is UB:
>
> ```rust
> let mut x = String::new();
> let p = &mut x as *mut String;
> let y = x;
> p.write(String::new());
> ```

I thought that the lifetime of `x` ends when it is moved to `y`. `p` is dangling while being `.write()` through. But why this is not decided as UB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the same thread, a bit further, there is this [other comment](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/59123#issuecomment-501437202) by *cramertj* that I think explains a bit this issue. The code exemplified in this other comment is:

```
let mut x = String::new();
let addr_x: *const String = reference_to_pointer(&x);
drop(x);
ptr::write(addr_x as *mut String, String::new());
```

The basic idea of this snippet is to be able to `drop` a local value to run its destructor and reuse its memory allocation to store a new value. This is a pattern that some think it may be useful, but others think it should be UB.

Remember that `drop()` is not a special function in any way, it just moves the `x` into its own scope that finishes immediately, so it is more or less equivalent to your original code. You could even use `forget()` or push the value into a container and the example still holds.

Note that this idiom is actually valid if you use allocated dynamic memory (it is what `Vec` does under the hood). The issue here is whether it is also valid for stack allocated automatic memory.

Comment: Good explanation. It's hard to imagine why this is allowed, though, even if the snippet appears meaningful at first glance. `x` was _moved_, so writing into the dead storage (even if legal) means that its `drop` will never run. How is that ever useful, except to write a version of `mem::forget` that allows you to keep referring to the object? `Vec` will run `ptr::drop_in_place()`, not `drop()`, so it's not exactly the same idiom. (Also, `Vec` will make sure that `ptr::write()` is followed by appropriate adjustment to len, so that the stored value is dropped at the right time.)

Comment: @user4815162342: Local variables are tricky. For example, `let mut a = String::new(); drop(a); a = String::new();`, it is guaranteed that the latter `a` has the same memory address as the former? And if I get a raw pointer to the first, can still be used? Maybe it is just crazy and it should be UB (use `MaybeUninit`) or maybe it has some legitimate uses. Futures or generators, maybe?

Comment: *For example, `let mut a = String::new(); drop(a); a = String::new();`, it is guaranteed that the latter a has the same memory address as the former?* - Sneaky question! I don't think there should be such a guarantee, I think moving from `a` should invalidate both the location and its contents. But I am beginning to see how the question is non-trivial.