# Why does the Rust compiler perform a copy when moving an immutable value?

Tags: optimization, rust

My intuition must be wrong about moves and copies. I would expect the Rust compiler optimize away moves of an immutable value as a no-op. Since the value is immutable, we can safely reuse it after the move. But [Rust 1.65.0 on Godbolt](https://rust.godbolt.org/z/Ezcnbjahs) compiles to assembly that copies the value to a new position in memory. The Rust code that I am studying:

```
pub fn f_int() {
    let x = 3;
    let y = x;
    println!("{}, {}", x, y);
}
```

The resulting assembly with `-C opt-level=3`:

```
    ; pub fn f_int() {
    sub     rsp, 88
    ; let x = 3;
    mov     dword ptr [rsp], 3
    ; let y = x;
    mov     dword ptr [rsp + 4], 3
    mov     rax, rsp
    ...
```

Why does `let y = x;` result in `mov dword ptr [rsp + 4], 3` and `mov rax, rsp`? Why doesn't the compiler treat `y` as the same variable as `x` in the assembly?

([This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67499399/why-does-the-rust-compiler-not-reuse-the-memory-on-the-stack-after-an-object-is) looks similar but it is about strings which are not Copy. My question is about integers which are Copy. It looks like what I am describing is not a missed optimization opportunity but a fundamental mistake in my understanding.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not call it a fundamental mistake in your understanding, but there are some interesting observations here.

First, `println!()` (and the formatting machinery in particular) is surprisingly hard to optimize, due to its design. So the fact that with `println!()` it was not optimized is not surprising.

Second, [it is generally not obvious it is OK to perform this optimization, because it observably make the addresses equivalent](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/can-we-pass-copy-values-by-immutable-reference/18057/5?u=chrefr). And `println!()` takes the address of the printed values (and passes them to an opaque function). In fact, `Copy` types are harder to justify than non-`Copy` types in that regard, because with `Copy` types the original variable may still be used after a move while with non-`Copy` types [it is possible that not](https://github.com/rust-lang/unsafe-code-guidelines/issues/188).

Comment: So is the `mov` performed in the assembly because the memory addresses are required to be different? What use case would it break if the addresses were allowed to be the same? I am confused because I would expect immutability to imply the reuse of the original memory address on a copy, as I think e.g. Haskell does.

Comment: @Student People expect that different allocations have different addresses. This is the point of e.g. `std::ptr::ptr_eq()` and people rely on that.

Answer (score 4):

If you change your example like this

```rust
pub fn f_int() -> i32 {
    let x = 3;
    let y = x;
    // println!("{}, {}", x, y);
    x+y
}
```

the optimisation takes place

```
example::f_int:
        mov     eax, 6
        ret
```

The `println!()` *macro* (as well as `write!()`...) takes references on its parameters and provides the formatting machinery with these references.
Probably, the compiler deduces that providing some functions (that are not inlined) with references requires the data being stored somewhere in memory in order to have an address.
Because the type is `Copy`, the semantics implies that we have two distinct storages, otherwise, sharing the storage would have been an optimisation for a *move* operation (not a *copy*).

Comment: That’s interesting about `x+y`!  Why is it a problem to pass on two identical memory addresses to such a function? Copy would imply that they are separate values, but due to immutability the compiler could safely assume that they are the same and store only one copy in memory. What would it break if the compiler did this?